# Fail to get PHPUnit test report in Azure Pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, phpunit, azure-pipelines

Fail to get PHPUnit test report in Azure Pipelines.

I want to get test result report of PHPUnit in Azure Pipelines, but got an error not finding the file:

```
Starting: PublishTestResults
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Test Results
Description  : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
Version      : 2.180.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results
==============================================================================
/usr/bin/dotnet --version
5.0.301
##[warning]No test result files matching **/result.xml were found.
Finishing: PublishTestResults
```

Here is the end of `azure-pipelines.yml`

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/result.xml'
```

the test run before the task, and got the right file.

```
lib/Cake/Console/cake test app All --debug --log-junit app/result.xml
```

What did I miss?

PHP: 5.3.29
PHPUnit: 3.7.38

Comment: Have you tried `testResultsFiles: '**/result.xml'`? Perhaps the path is different than expected, `**` will search within all directories.

Comment: @hakre I tried and updated the question, but got no luck. The pipeline itself was successful.

Comment: Okay then it really looks like the file is not there. a) it was never there (has never been created, the `cake test app All` command did not (fully) run) or b) it was created but then got deleted (e.g. a different pipeline step and artifact files not retained between them).

Comment: Sorry, You're right. I made a mistake in specifying the output path, `result.xml` instead of `app/result.xml`.
Probably docker mount wasn't working then.
Not it's working, Thank you.

Comment: leave an answer your own with a description how you could trouble-shoot it and what the fix was. This helps future visitors (and your future self) (yes, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question here on SO - after a short period you can even accept the answer yourself).